# Scala: how to extract a data from text file with the specified start and end keywords in scala

Tags: scala

I am writing below code however I am not able to get how to extract the data from given start and end position after getting the specified extracted data I would like to write the same extracted data into new file, please help me on this.

```
val f = scala.io.Source.fromFile("file.txt")

  for (line <- f.getLines())

    f.close()
```

Comment: There's no details of the "given start and end position" in your question. Please add those

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io._

val f = "fileopen.scala"
for (line <- Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines) {
    println(line)
}

val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("hello.txt" ))
pw.write(f)
pw.close
f.close
```

I am by no means an expert, but I hope this helped!

source:[scala cookbook](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-write-text-files-in-scala-printwriter-filewriter)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my concern is that I have to extract the data from one position to another position specified by reading the text file.And finally the only extracted data I have to write in new file.Please help.